# Scrolling a PageView

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to use a `PageView` with vertical axis and move between the pages using the mouse-scroll, but when I use the mouse-scroll the page don't scroll... The page only scroll when I click and swipe to up/down.

There is any way to do that?

*I want to keep the property `pageSnapping: true`*

The problem:

When I try to mouse-scroll the page, it don't change, it just back to initial offset.
But when I click and swipe works...

[image: Problem exemple]

```
class Body extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  PageController _controller = PageController(keepPage: true);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: Sizing.size.height,
        width: Sizing.size.width,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            PageView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              controller: _controller,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(color: Colors.red),
                Container(color: Colors.blue),
                Container(color: Colors.orange),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To use the mouse scroll you must disable the movement of the `PageView` by setting
`physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`.
Then you have to manually intercept the mouse scroll through a `Listener`. If you also want to recover the PageView classic movement through swipe you must use a `GestureDetector`.
Here is an example code:

```
class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  final PageController pageController = PageController();
  // this is like a lock that prevent update the PageView multiple times while is 
  // scrolling
  bool pageIsScrolling = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: GestureDetector(
        // to detect swipe
        onPanUpdate: (details) {
          _onScroll(details.delta.dy * -1);
        },
        child: Listener(
          // to detect scroll
          onPointerSignal: (pointerSignal) {
            if (pointerSignal is PointerScrollEvent) {
              _onScroll(pointerSignal.scrollDelta.dy);
            }
          },
          child: PageView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            controller: pageController,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            pageSnapping: true,
            children: [
               Container(color: Colors.red),
               Container(color: Colors.blue),
               Container(color: Colors.orange),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }

  void _onScroll(double offset) {
    if (pageIsScrolling == false) {
      pageIsScrolling = true;
      if (offset > 0) {
        pageController
            .nextPage(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                curve: Curves.easeInOut)
            .then((value) => pageIsScrolling = false);

        print('scroll down');
      } else {
        pageController
            .previousPage(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                curve: Curves.easeInOut)
            .then((value) => pageIsScrolling = false);
        print('scroll up');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool! I'll try it later

Answer (score 0):

To make stuff scrollable in general you can wrap the widget (>>right click on the widget you want to make scrollable>>refactor>>wrap with widget) in a `SingleChildScrollView()`.

Comment: I know that Widget, but the `PageView()` already is scrollable... And I having problems with it scroll.

Comment: Sorry I'm just a beginner didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Luca!

I just modified the entire thing to do the same, what was the question asked for.

```
  Listener(
                onPointerMove: (pointerMove) {
                  if (pointerMove is PointerMoveEvent) {
                    _onScroll(pointerMove.delta.dy * -1);
                    print(pointerMove.delta.dy);
                  }
                },
                onPointerSignal: (pointerSignal) {
                  if (pointerSignal is PointerScrollEvent) {
                    _onScroll(pointerSignal.scrollDelta.dy);
                    print(pointerSignal.scrollDelta.dy);
                  }
                },
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Container(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                        minHeight: SizeConfig.screenHeight * .9),
                    width: SizeConfig.screenWidth,
                    height: SizeConfig.screenWidth / 2,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                            image: AssetImage(
                                'assets/images/background_circles.png'))),
                    child: PageView(
                      controller: _pageController,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      pageSnapping: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      children: [
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Flutter Web, the Listview/Pageview builder doesn't detect the mouse/touch/stylus drag event. You should add scrollConfiguration to include such drag events.

You can either add the scrollConfiguration globally through the app or only for those specific widgets that involve such drag events.

Step - 1: Create a custom scroll configuration to include the drag devices that might be used in your web app.

For example:

```
class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
 
  // Override behavior methods and getters like dragDevices
  // You can override either Material/Cupertino ScrollBehavior
  @override
   Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => { 
   PointerDeviceKind.touch,
   PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
   // etc.
  };
}
```

Step -2: Add an instance of this in the scrollBehaviour property in MaterialApp for a global scroll configuration and for a specific widget simply wrap the listview/pageview builder with [ScrollConfiguration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollConfiguration-class.html) and add an instance of the above scrollBehavior in the behavior property.

For example:

```
 final ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
 
 ScrollConfiguration(
   behavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
   child: ListView.builder(
     controller: controller,
     itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Text('Item $index');
     }
   ),
 );
```

For more details - Refer to this [flutter doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/default-scroll-behavior-drag).